# Como selecionar registro por posição

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

pode me dizer como posso selecionar um registro por posição?

como faria pra busca o registro de maria?
obs: não buscar por id ou nome

encontrei o take no guia, mas ele busca o primeiro e a posição. 
ex:

```
Person.take(3) // ele pegaria fabio e maria
```

Banco:

Fabio

Roberto

Maria

Joao

diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`take` na verdade pega os 3 primeiros registros (utiliza `LIMIT` para isso)
Ex:

`Person.take(3)`

geraria um sql: `SELECT  "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios" LIMIT 3`

Para poucos registros algo como a solução abaixo, resolveria:

`Person.take(3)[2] # terceiro registro`

Mas para uma solução mais performática não recomendaria essa solução, já que para fazer uma consulta a uma posição muito distante, esse método iria trazer consigo uma quantidade enorme de dados.

Por exemplo, pegar o item 1.000.000 teria que buscar esses milhões de registros.

Caso você tenha outros fatores para maior limitação desses dados, essa solução pode ser utilizada.

Answer (score 1):

Com a amostra de registros proposta,

`Person.third`

retornaria o registro 'maria'.